# very old chinese language

Tags: history

[image]

I need help to determine this brand

How old is the brand?
Is it a stamp or a tax stamp?
Does it have something to do with the silk tax?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the site is not for image recognition.

Comment: @zyy It's so strange attitude. First, Guys decide translation as off-topic. And then ancient stamps or paintings or coins are acceptable. While nobody actually cares about the massive amount of asking for translation problem. And now an ancient Chinese character recognition is off-topic again.

Comment: Turn the image 90 degree counterclockwise 蠶種改濟之章 - seal of silkworm type improvement

Comment: @神秘德里克 The main point is, I would say, asking for translation is somewhat acceptable, but the poster is expected to show at least some effort in trying to solve the problem.

Comment: I generally accept character identification questions if even putting in effort is unlikely to achieve identification. The characters in this one are easily identifiable.

Answer (score 2):

imo, the other answer is significantly "inventive" :)

, as @tang ho indicated, the correct reading should be "蠶種改濟之章".

and, these're kanji, japanese related (it's 繭印紙 蚕種印紙)

here's relevant pic & link:

[image]

https://buyee.jp/item/yahoo/auction/j511816810?lang=en

i would suggest the op ask again in japanese stack exchange.

https://japanese.stackexchange.com

have fun :)

Answer (score -3):

This is NOT an ancient stamp，but a marketing gimmick to make it looks like "old stuff".

- The correct way of reading this"蠶改之, 種濟章"
- 蠶改之 mean silkworm farm that using improving converting farming mechanism, ask the local for the story.
- 濟章 is area in China, it mean 临济、章丘.  Mostly a tea leaf distribution center, not much of tea plant there.
- There are an on-going tea leaf speculation going around in China.

In short, you should not bother about the "brand". It is not recommended to join in the speculative frenzy, unless you are one of those who want to take advantage of others gullible people.

Comment: These are modern China traditional word that follow the current horizontal printing habits.

Comment: I cannot find a place named 濟章 on Google. 蠶改之 even makes no sense to me. And how do “tea” and “farm” come out？

Comment: So you mean this is a box of tea？

Comment: @TooskyHierot the red stamping say 儿副茶.

Comment: Nope. It's 夈副儿 Though I don't know what it means.

Comment: @TooskyHierot Neither I. Honestly, only OP can confirmed the product.